# In Dart WebUI how to invoke a method on load for an element

Tags: dart, dart-webui, web-component

In Dart I am attempting something like:

```dart
<element name="x-facet-select" constructor="SelectOptions" extends="div">
<template>
  <div>
    <select bind-value="str" on-click="update()" on-load="init()" id="outputitems" multiple="multiple">
```

I can't get the on-load (or onload, or anything) method to run in the SelectOptions call.  It's jus a simple print Hello World line to console as a test.

Is there a way in Dart's WebUI to invoke a method on the initial loading of an element?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run code after the user changes the drop down value:

```html
<select id="list" on-change="selectionChanged($event)">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>
```

```dart
class SelectOptionsComponent extends WebComponent {
  selectionChanged(Event e) {
    print(__list.value);
  }
}
```

That would be all.

**Update:** Looks like you also want to run some code after the component is ready, try `inserted()`:

```dart
class SelectOptionsComponent extends WebComponent {
  selectionChanged(Event e) {
    print(__list.value);
  }

  inserted() {
    // populate __list here.
    (__list as OListElement).innerHtml = '<option>bar</option>'; // Just an example.
  }
}
```

Comment: Kai, thanks, but what I am interested is if I can do an on-load to init the data in the select element.  The updates are change are working fine for me.